# Unable to use alias with receiveOnly

Tags: d

```d
public alias Message = int;
void threadFunc(){
    import std.concurrency;
    while(true){
        auto m = receiveOnly!(Message);
    }
}

void main(){
    import core.thread;
    import std.concurrency;

    auto t = spawn(&threadFunc);
}
```

> Error: ScopeDsymbol breeze.concurrency.task.__anonymous.__anonymous struct std.concurrency.Message is private

I am unable to use aliases with `receiveOnly`. It seems that D makes them private my default but I explicitly marked `Message`as public, but the errors still exists.

Comment: What version of the compiler are you using? It compiles for me just fine with 2.071.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is with name of alias `Message` it conflicts with private struct in `std.concurrency`. This has been fixed in 2.071.0 release. So you can upgrade or change a name of alias to something else.

More info: https://dlang.org/changelog/2.071.0.html#dip22 and here: http://www.schveiguy.com/blog/2016/03/import-changes-in-d-2-071/